# Microsoft Dynamics 365 and ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: .net-core, dynamics-crm, asp.net-core-webapi, workflow

I am working on an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API project, and I have some actions that need approval from a specific user to be implemented.

For example: the user wants to update the price of a product, but this action needs approval from his manager to be completed.

I was trying to find a workflow engine that works well with .NET and since the organization that I'm working for already has Dynamics 365 and it has its own workflow engine, I'm trying to use it with the project to handle actions that need a workflow.

Any help or suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good fit for flow approvals.

In short, create a table in dynamics to track your request and trigger a flow approval off the create of the record.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/modern-approvals

The example shows SharePoint being used to trigger an approval, but that can simply be replaced by dataverse (the engine the d365 is running on)

Edit : this vid has a walk though of its use  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VHiDP13U_HM

Comment: that's not what I really want, I want something
like camunda :https://docs.camunda.io/docs/guides/ so I can track the workflow in Dynamic 365 inside my project for example I want to receive the result of something like condition and trigger an event of execute some functions from my code

Comment: Yes,  that is what the power platform is, dynamics 365 is built on that system which gives you access to all of those capabilities. Flow approvals is an approvals engine included in the power platform. Power automate is the workflow system, working in conjunction with Power Apps (ui engine) and Dataverse (data storage/ business engine). If you have d365, you have access to all of it.  From dataverse you can also trigger web hooks, eventhub events, and service bus events based on triggers or api events.